# Reloding page in browser i get error from webpack with connection

Tags: vue.js, asp.net-core, webpack

In my vuejs spa on firefox and safari i get following message in console
when i reload page (or submit a form with post action)

**The connection with https://localhost:5000/dist/__ webpack_hmr was interrupted while the page was loading.**

I use netcore 2.1 as server side

My dependency are

```
"devDependencies": {
    "aspnet-webpack": "^2.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.25.0",
    "event-source-polyfill": "^0.0.7",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0-rc",
    "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.2.5",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "vue": "^2.2.2",
    "vue-loader": "^11.1.4",
    "vue-router": "^2.3.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.2.2",
    "webpack": "^2.2.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.12.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@deveodk/vue-toastr": "^1.0.4",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "bootstrap-vue": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "nprogress": "^0.2.0",
    "vee-validate": "^2.2.0",
    "velocity-animate": "^1.5.2",
    "vue-slider-component": "^2.8.12",
    "vuex": "^3.1.0"
  }
```

In my startup i set

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseWebpackDevMiddleware(new WebpackDevMiddlewareOptions 
                {
                    HotModuleReplacement = true
                   ,HotModuleReplacementEndpoint = "/__webpack_hmr"
                });
            }
```

Im going crazy and not understand why? Seems works well only in chrome

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is requesting `__webpack_hmr` from the dist folder, try to use below code in your startup:

```
app.UseWebpackDevMiddleware(new WebpackDevMiddlewareOptions {
            HotModuleReplacement = true,
            HotModuleReplacementEndpoint = "/dist/__webpack_hmr"
        });
```

Refer to https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/issues/1204

Comment: Sorry i paste wrong path...i already try that and it not works. Do not know why. I get a page reload if also i submit a form with post action. im going crazy

Comment: i note a server error log "message template error" about "Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Webpack.ConditionalProxyMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)"...could be related?